# META Business api customize logo in qr code

Tags: qr-code, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I am using META for developers WhatsApp Cloud api to generate QR code.
I can generate and edit qr.
Also using account dashboard, I can do the same.

```
curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/106540352242922/message_qrdls' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer EAAJB...' \
-d '
{
  "prefilled_message": "Cyber Monday",
  "generate_qr_image": "SVG"
}'
```

[Full Documentaion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-management-api/qr-codes/)

I need to customize the default logo image inside the QR code. I need to add organization logo in place of it.
Is it possible?